# Akka 2.0-RC1 repository URL

Tags: maven, akka

What is the maven repository that carries Akka 2.0 RC1 jars? I am looking at http://www.akka.io/repository/se/scalablesolutions/akka/akka/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://akka.io/repository is the backwards-compat repo

use akka.io/releases:

http://akka.io/releases/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor/2.0-RC2/